# How to add up multi UILabels that was created from multi UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSwResults;

- (IBAction)SegSwOne:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *SegSwOne;
- (IBAction)SegSwTwo:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *SegSwTwo;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblResOne
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblResTwo;
```

in the .m file

```
- (IBAction)SegSwOne:(id)sender {
    switch (self.SegSwOne.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.lblResOne.text =@"50";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.lblResOne.text =@"200";
            break;
        case 2:
            self.lblResOne.text =@"400";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)SegSwTwo:(id)sender {
    switch (self.SegSwTwo.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.lblResTwo.text =@"50";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.lblResTwo.text =@"150";
            break;
        case 2:
            self.lblResTwo.text =@"400";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

What i am tiring to do, is that if you select a different `UISegmentedControl` it changes the number in the `UILabel`   lblSwResults ….  so if case0 and case2 = “ 450 “ in the results label…

Looking at it to be automatic - showing a dynamic change of values when you change value in the SegSwOne or SegSwTwo…  What is the best why to code this..?   Do i need to create a float value for each one and then make a formula NSString for the RESULTS ???

Any help would be great or a link so I can find out more….? Cheers

Comment: Proper (or at least better) formatting, spelling, grammar, and punctuation may help your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd so something like the following:

Create two methods that return a value for each segment:

```
- (int)segmentOneValue:(NSInteger)index {
    static int values[] = { 50, 200, 400 };

    return values[index];
}

- (int)segmentTwoValue:(NSInteger)index {
    static int values[] = { 50, 150, 400 };

    return values[index];
}
```

Then your two segmented control actions would be:

```
- (IBAction)SegSwOne:(UISegmentControl *)control {
    int valueOne = [self segmentOneValue:control.selectedSegmentIndex];
    int valueTwo = [self segmentTwoValue:self.SegSwTwo.selectedSegmentIndex];

    self.lblResOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueOne];
    self.lblSwResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueOne + valueTwo];
}

- (IBAction)SegSwTwo:(UISegmentControl *)control {
    int valueTwo = [self segmentOneValue:control.selectedSegmentIndex];
    int valueOne = [self segmentTwoValue:self.SegSwOne.selectedSegmentIndex];

    self.lblResTwo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueTwo];
    self.lblSwResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueOne + valueTwo];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy, this is what i was looking for - added a few more viables and works great thanks...  changed the [control.selectedSegmentIndex]  for example ---   int valueOne = [self segmentOneValue:self.SegSWOne.selectedSegmentIndex];  and replaced the  :(UISegmentControl *)control to  :(id)sender { ---  thanks once again sisimon